# C# export to Excel UTF-8 issue

Tags: c#, excel, utf-8

I'm tring to export som data to **xls**, but seem to have a problem with the UTF-8 encoding.
It exports fine and I get the Excel file looking at it should, but when the inserted data has special characters, in this case, danish characters as **æ**, **ø** and **å**, then the file is somewhat currupted. When I try to open it in Excel, I get a message that a problem occured in reading the file, and mentions the problem as **Setting of the spreadseet**.

I ran validation of the resulted XML in few online validation services which passed the validation. When I ran it in the Notepad++ XML validator, I got an error in the først found special char (which was **Å**) which says: **XML Parsing error at line XX: Input is not proper UTF-8, Indicate encoding!**

Can someone point out what that meens?
where should I indicate the encoding?

Here are the relevant parts of the resulting XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Created>2006-09-25T13:34:53Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2014-05-20T18:04:40Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>12.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <RemovePersonalInformation/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>7875</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>14895</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>360</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>300</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>

 ...

 </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Ark1">
  <Names>
   <NamedRange ss:Name="GIS34_Skade_V1_alle_koder" ss:RefersTo="=Ark1!R5C2:R28C2"/>
  </Names>
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="16" ss:ExpandedRowCount="34" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:StyleID="s16" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:StyleID="s16" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="30"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s16" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="135" ss:Span="2"/>
   <Column ss:Index="5" ss:StyleID="s19" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="30"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s16" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="135"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s19" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="30"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s16" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="135"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s19" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Span="3"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="30" ss:StyleID="s18">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s33"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s126"><Data ss:Type="String">LE34</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">Kunde:</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s32"><Data ss:Type="String">Assens Kommune</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="30" ss:StyleID="s18">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s33"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s128"><Data ss:Type="String">GIS34</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s87"><Data ss:Type="String">Kodeliste:</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s32"><Data ss:Type="String">Arkil Århus V2</Data></Cell> <!-- Error occures in this line first because of the **Å** char -->
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s33"/>
    <Cell ss:MergeAcross="6" ss:StyleID="s37"><Data ss:Type="String">Udformning af lagkontrol: </Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
   </Row>

   ...

   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:Index="2" ss:StyleID="s29"><NamedCell ss:Name="GIS34_Skade_V1_alle_koder"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"><Data ss:Type="String">Billede 3 (filename)</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s30"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s20"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s16"/>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.31496062992125984"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.31496062992125984"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.74803149606299213" x:Left="0.70866141732283472" x:Right="0.70866141732283472" x:Top="0.74803149606299213"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Print>
    <ValidPrinterInfo/>
    <PaperSizeIndex>9</PaperSizeIndex>
    <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
    <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
    <Gridlines/>
   </Print>
   <Selected/>
   <FreezePanes/>
   <FrozenNoSplit/>
   <SplitHorizontal>7</SplitHorizontal>
   <TopRowBottomPane>7</TopRowBottomPane>
   <ActivePane>2</ActivePane>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
     <Number>2</Number>
     <ActiveRow>26</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>13</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
  <QueryTable xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Name>GIS34 Skade V1_alle koder</Name>
   <AutoFormatFont/>
   <AutoFormatPattern/>
   <QuerySource>
    <QueryType>Text</QueryType>
    <TextWizardSettings>
     <Name x:HRef="C:\Temp\dummy.txt"/>
     <Decimal>,</Decimal>
     <ThousandSeparator>.</ThousandSeparator>
     <TrailingMinusNumbers/>
     <FormatSettings>
      <FieldType>AutoFormat</FieldType>
     </FormatSettings>
     <Delimiters>
      <Tab/>
     </Delimiters>
    </TextWizardSettings>
    <VersionLastEdit>3</VersionLastEdit>
    <VersionLastRefresh>3</VersionLastRefresh>
   </QuerySource>
  </QueryTable>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Here is how I export:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");
context.Response.ContentEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
context.Response.Write(excel);
```

**Update 1:**

I now changed the export code to the following where I encode the string as UTF-8, getting **no** good results:

```
string excel = header.ToString() + styles.ToString() + title.ToString() + content.ToString() + footer.ToString();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");
//context.Response.ContentEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(excel);
context.Response.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
```

**Update 2:**

Changes again to this (suggested by @Luaan), but still the same:

```
string excel = header.ToString() + styles.ToString() + title.ToString() + content.ToString() + footer.ToString();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(excel));
```

Comment: If you use OpenXML the resulting xml has to have a line that specifies the encoding (something like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>) which i am not seeing in your file. Also if your xlsx is invalid, change the xlsx extension into a zip, inspect the xml structure, play around with it until you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I don't think this is OpenXML, isn't this the legacy XML format for Excel? In any case, is `excel` a string or a byte array? Are you clearing the output first? Writing a byte array would be safer, probably - it might help you against double-encoding.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, it's not OpenXML, was just making a point regarding the missing encoding="UTF-8" attribute, with which I have experience.

Comment: @Luaan, the `excel` is a string. I tried encoding this string to UTF-8 (see my update), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

instead - and make sure the XML is actually in UTF-8. Setting the `Content-Encoding` HTTP header will not help you.

**EDIT**: Your update doesn't encode anything (in fact, you're likely to introduce even more problems that way), you're sending it as string again.

Instead, you want to write the `byte[]`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(excel));
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, adding the encoding="utf-8" didn't change the outcome

Comment: @Ambran: Adding the attribute isn't enough, the XML *has* to be in proper UTF-8.

Comment: Luaan, I changed to (Update 2) but it's the same. 
I'm beggining to think that problem lies elseware. Would it be more helpfull if I publish the whole C# code and whole resulting XML?

Comment: @Ambran It might very well be in your XML generation code (it's obvious you're just slapping strings together instead of using a XmlDocument or something like that). Try debugging a bit deeper - what happens if you put a correct XML into `excel` before writing it to output?

Comment: Luaan, the data set is selected by the user. Some dataset result a fine sheet, and some don't. I'll have to go through the XML line by line to identify what goes wrong.

Comment: Looks like it's failing if it has more then 750 lines of XML. Do you know of any limit in this relation?

Comment: @Ambran That shouldn't be an issue, at least on the ASP.NET side of things. Requests are limited, but IIRC responses should work pretty much always.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to solve this is set charset in HttpContext.Current.Response as below:

```
            HttpContext.Current..Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
```

Most complete part of code:

```
            curContext.Response.Clear();
            curContext.Response.Buffer = true;
            curContext.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
            curContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            curContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName + ".xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some library that can do it correctly and you will save lot of time, e.g.

- http://closedxml.codeplex.com/
- http://freenetexcel.codeplex.com/
- http://epplus.codeplex.com/
- http://npoi.codeplex.com/